# NodeJS and socket.io can't send message

Tags: node.js, socket.io

today I follow an tutorial by Gonzalo Ayuso at http://gonzalo123.com/2011/05/23/real-time-notifications-part-ii-now-with-node-js-and-socket-io/ but it can't send the message
Here is my server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
});
server.listen(8000);

//socket.io
var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.set('transports', ['websocket']);

console.log("Start");
socket.on('connection', function(client){
      client.on('message', function(msg){
          console.log(msg);
          socket.broadcast(msg);
      })
    });
```

and the client.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Comet Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a id='customAlert' href="#" onclick='socket.send("customAlert")'>publish customAlert</a></p>
        <p><a id='customAlert2' href="#" onclick='socket.send("customAlert2")'>publish customAlert2</a></p>
        <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
// Start the socket
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have edited it just a little bit to run on my server. But the client doesn't send message to server. Can anybody help me? Sorry for my bad English.

I have found out that the client can't connect to server but I don't know why?

My computer is running xampp with apache server. Maybe it's problem?

Updated:
I have just set transports to xhr-polling and it connect success. Why doesn't it accept websocket?

Comment: What's your target browser? Open developer tools and check out if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m? Maybe it doesn't support socket.io. I have read somewhere that their Socket are not the same.

Comment: It first connects with websocket, but immediately requests to 101 switching protocol.

Answer (score 0):

you need to read more carefully the tutorials about socket.io
first of all to call some event, you need to emit the event name:

```
socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
```

thats mean, on your onclick in anchor need to call socket.emit ..., or to call some function like:

```
function call_my_event(name){

    socket.emit(name,{my : 'data'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out my problem. It's about firewall or proxy or something else in my computer block websocket protocol. I tested that code on another computer and it works fine. So I have to re-install my system and websocket is available for me :D